# Gradient and stochastic gradient descent for loss function and regularizer

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, error-function, gradient-descent

We have to calculate the gradient for:

$\sum_{i=1}^n$ log$(1+exp(-y_i* \textbf{w}^T x_i)) + \frac{1}{b} \sum_{i=1}^d w_i^4$

and to write down pseudo-code for stochastic gradient descent of this function with respect to $\textbf{w}$.

Here my solutions - I would appreciate some feedback to know if these are correct:

- Gradient:

$\sum_{i=1}^n$ $\frac{-y_i*x_i*exp(-y_i*\textbf{w}^T*x_i)}{(1+exp(-y_i* \textbf{w}^T x_i)} + \frac{4}{b}\sum_{i=1}^d {w_i}^3 $

- Stochastic gradient descent pseudocode:

(1) Random initialization of weight vector w and choice of stepsize $\eta$

(2) For data samples i,...,n determine the next weight-vector with dimension L iteratively as follows:

$(...,w_l,...)^T = (...,w_l,...)^T - \eta ([...,\frac{-y_i*x_{il}*exp(-y_i*{w}_l*x_{il})}{(1+exp(-y_i* {w}_l x_{il})} + \frac{4}{b}\sum w_i^3,...)$

Comment: You forgot the $4w_i^3$ in your gradient. Also, you seem to be giving yourself some confusion about $x$. I'm guessing it's a matrix, so that $x_i$ is a vector. Does your last line make sense, then? Increasing a scalar coordinate by a vector?

Comment: That was/is indeed my confusion. So thinking about it conceptually: Our weight vector has as many dimensions as our problem space, we update the weight vector for each datasample, more specifically every entry of the weight vector regarding every coordinate of our problem space - is that correct now? Also, in the gradient, I corrected the last summand to $1/b*\sum 4*w_i^3$

Comment: Closer! You're correct that x must be indexed by $l$. But still the issue that you need to get a scalar; x is a matrix, so x_l is a vector. And you know that y_l can't be right, since l might range over a broader range than y is long! That should stay at y_i.

Comment: If you still can't get it I'll post an answer showing a correct working

Comment: Ok, I think slowly I am getting it: We derive for each of the elements of weight vector w (i.e. for each of the L dimensions). For a datasample x_i, the corresponding y_i is a scalar (?). x_i itself is however a l-dimensional vector, so for each line we would actually look at a particular element of this vector, i.e. x_il? If it is waay too off I would appreciate an answer of course. Many thanks for the support!

Comment: No that's exactly right! :) Each sample (y_i) contributes to each component of the model (w_l) once, with the corresponding features (x_il). Try revising your formula one more time with this in mind.

Comment: Revisited/corrected the post - thank you very much! A question: If we update our gradient with regards to each single datasample, do we average over these updates at the end to determine the minima..? Also, I have 2 more questions regarding optimization which I will post in the next days, could I bother you again?